# If $A$ is context-free then $A^*$ is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

I am currently studying for my exam and I am having trouble to solve this question:

> Right or wrong: If $A$ is context-free then $A^*$ is regular.

I think it's wrong because if $A$ is context-free it means that $A$ can be a non-regular language. And the non-regular languages are not closed under the Kleene star operation (at least I think so). I am not sure how write this in a more formal way.

Maybe like this?

Let $A=\{a^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then we know that $A$ is non-regular and context-free. However, I'm not sure what $A^*$ is.

Comment: For your example, $A$ means "balanced nested brackets" and $A^*$ means "balanced bracket sequence". Both are context-free and non-regular (you can prove that counting their residuals).

Comment: In your example $A^* \cap a^*b^* = A$. That should help.

Comment: @HendrikJan How it that going to help me ? Please dont tell me the solution, maybe just a little hint.

Comment: @Frank Hendrik Jan gave you a huge hint.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I dont understand the benefit from the hint. Can you give me a second hint or a question which will lead me to the right way?

Comment: @Frank You know that $A$ is non-regular, that $a^*b^*$ is regular, and that $A^* \cap a^*b^* = A$, and want to deduce that $A^*$ is non-regular.

Comment: Oh, ok. I had not in mind that a*b* is regular. Okay so the proof will be like that: 
Assume A* is regular, then $A^* \cap a^*b^*$ must be regular because the regular languagues are closed under intersection. This is a contradiction since we know that $A^* \cap a^*b^*=A$  is regular. Therefore A* cant be regular.

Comment: @Dmitry Perhaps it is interesting to note that the bracket sequences in $A^*$ do not comprise all nested sequences (or Dyck words). For instance $aababb$ is properly nested, but not covered by the star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\{a^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then we know that $A$ is non-regular and context-free. Also we can see that $A^*\cap a^*b^*=A$. Since $a^*b^*$ is a regular expression, we do know that it is regular. Lets assume that A* is regular.

The regular languagues are closed unter intersection. Therefore $A^*\cap a^*b^*$ must be also regular(because we assume that $A^*$ is regular). This would implicate that A is regular because  $A^*\cap a^*b^*=A$. This is a contradiction because we know that A is not regular. Therefore A* cant be regular.

$q.e.d$

Comment: case closed :-)